# Parameter group for SET GLOBAL foreign_key_checks in RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I am using RDS AWS for my mysql instance. Currently, i need to set global foreign_key_checks in RDS. but it says that I need a super priviledge access to do so. I realise I might miss to set the parameter group for this command. Could  I know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you ever want to `SET GLOBAL FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`?

Comment: because i need it